# Pandas Convert Dataframe Values to Labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert values within the current dataframe as the "Index" and the dataframe's Index as the "Labels". For Example:

```
    Value1    Value2
0     0         1
1     2         4
2     NaN       3
```

This would result in

```
    Labels    
0     0         
1     0         
2     1    
3     2
4     1
```

Currently I managed to do this using a loop to check and apply the necessary labels/values but with millions of labels to mark this process becomes extremely time consuming. Is there a way to do this in a smarter and quicker way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they integers?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, at least `Value1` can't be integer because it has `NaN`'s

Comment: Yes the dataframe's datatype is integer. But can contain NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
s = df.stack() 
df = pd.DataFrame(s.index.get_level_values(0).values,
                  columns=['Labels'],
                  index=s.values.astype(int)).sort_index()
print (df)
   Labels
0       0
1       0
2       1
3       2
4       1
```

Detail:

```
print (df.stack())
0  Value1    0.0
   Value2    1.0
1  Value1    2.0
   Value2    4.0
2  Value2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a really good one (thanks to the collective effort of the pandas community). This one should be fast.

It uses the power a flexibility of `repeat` and `ravel` to flatten your data.

```
s = pd.Series(df.index.repeat(2), index=df.values.ravel())
s[s.index.notnull()].sort_index()

0.0    0
1.0    0
2.0    1
3.0    2
4.0    1
dtype: int64
```

A subsequent conversion results in an integer index:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```

---

A similar (slightly faster depending on your data) solution which also results in an integer index is performing the filtering before converting to `Series` -

```
v = df.index.repeat(df.shape[1])
i = df.values.ravel()

m = ~np.isnan(i)
s = pd.Series(v[m], index=i[m].astype(int)).sort_index()
```

```
s

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

---

**Performance**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# jezrael's solution

%%timeit
s = df2.stack()
pd.DataFrame(s.index.get_level_values(0).values,
             columns=['Labels'],
             index=s.values.astype(int)).sort_index()

4.57 ms ± 220 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
s = pd.Series(df2.index.repeat(2), index=df2.values.ravel())
s[s.index.notnull()].sort_index()

3.12 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
v = df2.index.repeat(df.shape[1])
i = df2.values.ravel()
m = ~np.isnan(i)
s = pd.Series(v[m], index=i[m].astype(int)).sort_index()

3.1 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```